# Add Google suggestions to custom search provider in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, search-engine, search-suggestion, google-suggest

my custom search provider for Firefox is broken. It worked like a charm until very recently. Can somebody show me how to fix it? It looks like this.

```
<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
    <ShortName>Google Encrypted</ShortName>
    <Description>Google Encrypted Search</Description>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
    <Image width="16" height="16">data:image/png;base64,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</Image>
    <Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="GET" template="https://encrypted.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&amp;q={searchTerms} "/>
    <Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://encrypted.google.com/search">
        <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
    </Url>
    <SearchForm>https://encrypted.google.com/</SearchForm>
</SearchPlugin>
```

With no luck I've tried the new suggestions URL `http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&amp;q={searchTerms}`.
Thankful for any advice!

Comment: Update your tags to have opensearch thats what this thing is called [MDN Docs - OpenSearch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox) used to be called Sherlock maybe you can add that in too

Answer (score 0):

I think your search template url is wrong. Try using:
`https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q={searchTerms}`
with no space at the end, you have a space

Comment: This is what's in the `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\searchplugins\google.xml` file, but it doesn't work for a custom search. Did you try it?